# How to show server side error message inside bootstrap modal popup in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I want to show server side error massage like duplicate name inside bootstrap modal popup using bootstrap Alert.Everything seems to work but message is not showing on submitting form.
My controller's code is(only return part):

```
TempData["Msg"] = "There are a record with the same description";                        
return PartialView("_Create", state);
```

And inside Partial view i have following code in header section:

```
@{
   var errorMessage = "";
   if (TempData["Msg"] != null)
   {
       errorMessage = @TempData["Msg"].ToString();
   }

}

<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-     label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
<h4 class="modal-title"><b>State</b></h4>
</div>

@if (errorMessage != "")
{

  <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger" id="success-alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    @errorMessage
  </div>

}
else
{
  <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger" id="success-alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the value in TempData is only stored only until you extract it from TempData. You are doing this when you perform check if the Msg is null. You can extract the value once and store it in a variable to use later. The other option is to use ViewBag or ViewData instead.

Comment: I have debugged my solution and code is successfully reaching inside IF block with message but message is not showing.Also this method works fine when i don't use partial view.

Comment: Try to store the value inside the variable and use it in your code

Comment: As you said i have declared a variable and accordingly i have updated my code above in my question.But still not working.When i first display popup it shows blank alert panel with no message(which i will correct).But when i hit save button inside popup then alert panel gets disappeared.

Comment: Save your error message before you check for null. `var errorMessage=@TempData["Msg"]; if(errorMessage != null)` and so on

Comment: I am getting error when i opening popup for the first time from main view due to null value of @TempData["Msg"].

Comment: As you said i initialized @TempData["Msg"] with empty string when popup first time opening and used if(errorMessage != null).But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

On your main page give the link

```
<a href="#myModal" id="modalLink" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Change Password</a>
```

and define some div

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
        <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
            <div class="modal-content" style="height:400px;width:350px;">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Change Password</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.Partial("_ChangePassword", Model.ObjChangePasswordModel)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

write some script for clear all validation messages and controls data on close popup

```
 $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $(this)
          .find("input,textarea,select,span")
             .val('')
             .end()
          .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
             .prop("checked", "")
             .end();

        $('.field-validation-error').each(function () {
            $(this).html("");
        })


    })
```

code on partial view

```
@model CAT_MVC.Models.ChangePasswordModel
```

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

```
<div style="height:400px;width:350px;">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <label for="CurrentPassword" class="form-control-label">Enter Current Password:</label>
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.CurrentPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtCurrentPassword", style = "width: 300px;padding-bottom:1px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CurrentPassword, "", new { @class = "message" })
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <label for="NewPassword" class="form-control-label">Enter New Password:</label>
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 300px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword, "", new { @class = "message" })
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">@*  *@
        <label for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control-label">Confirm Password:</label>
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 300px;" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "message" })
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "message" })
    </div>
    <div style="height:30px;vertical-align:top;">
        <div class="message lblmsg field-validation-error"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="button" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>&nbsp;
            <button type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Change Password</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

write script for validate server side and display error message and if no error then call server side submit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var element = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("VerifyOldPassword", "Account")',
            data: {
                CurrentPassword: $('#txtCurrentPassword').val(),
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != null && response.success) {
                    $(element).closest("form").submit();
                   // alert("Password changed successfully.");
                } else {
                    $('.lblmsg').html(response.responseText);
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("error!");  //
            }
        });
    });
    $('#btnCancel').click(function () {
        $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
    });
});
```